# New user asking questions about Laravel that are clearly answered in docs

Tags: discussion, new-users

A new user has signed up and in a short space of time asked multiple questions on how to do simple things in PHP framework Laravel, whose answers can be easily found by reading the official online documentation for a couple of minutes.

What is the course of action for this? As people are just answered the questions to get easy reputation boosts, and it’s not really helpful as they’re not really programming issues—just symptoms of laziness on the user’s behalf.

Comment: The down-vote tooltip includes *"does not show any research effort"* - this clearly applies here!

Comment: I’ve down-voted the questions and added comments saying the question they‘re asking is clearly covered in the documentation. I just wondered if there were anything that could be done as a moderator to… “point” the user to thinking before they post.

Comment: I guess the core problem is that, downvotes and comments notwithstanding, *they're getting the answers*. However, there isn't much you can do about that. If the OP persists in asking questions that attract downvotes, they will get throttled/banned, but if other users want to answer bad questions they can (I don't think they should, but that's a whole other discussion).